# Why does SNMP convert Counter64 to Counter?

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I need to send custom data over SNMP, and for this I use a script in Python, which takes the data and parses it. This is the output of script:

```
# ./SnmpGrafico.py
get
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255.2.2.11471
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255.2.2.11471
Counter64
57900010775
```

Here's my output using SNMP with the OID pointing to this script:

```
# snmpget -v 2c -c cocacola 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255.2.2.11471
UCD-SNMP-MIB::ucdavis.255.2.2.11471 = Counter32: 4294967295
```

And the SNMP config:

```
pass_persist .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255 /usr/local/bin/python3.3 /testRRD/SnmpGrafico.py
```

Why does SNMP parse my Counter64 to Counter32 and loses the original value? In this case the original value is "57900010775" and SNMP response "4294967295".

Thanks!

Update:

The dump SNMP

```
[root@wsRRDint2 testRRD]# snmpget -v 2c -c cocacola 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255.2.2.11471 -d

Sending 50 bytes to UDP: [127.0.0.1]:161
0000: 30 30 02 01  01 04 08 63  6F 63 61 63  6F 6C 61 A0    00.....cocacola.
0016: 21 02 04 7C  A6 4B 26 02  01 00 02 01  00 30 13 30    !..|.K&......0.0
0032: 11 06 0D 2B  06 01 04 01  8F 65 81 7F  02 02 D9 4F    ...+.....e.....O
0048: 05 00                                                 ..


Received 55 bytes from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:161
0000: 30 35 02 01  01 04 08 63  6F 63 61 63  6F 6C 61 A2    05.....cocacola.
0016: 26 02 04 7C  A6 4B 26 02  01 00 02 01  00 30 18 30    &..|.K&......0.0
0032: 16 06 0D 2B  06 01 04 01  8F 65 81 7F  02 02 D9 4F    ...+.....e.....O
0048: 41 05 00 FF  FF FF FF                                 A......

UCD-SNMP-MIB::ucdavis.255.2.2.11471 = Counter32: 4294967295
[root@wsRRDint2 testRRD]#
```

Comment: Use the dump switch of `snmpget` to print out raw bytes of the packets and then see what exactly is passed on the wire.

Comment: added, thanks! @LexLi

Comment: Please take more care with your grammar and spelling. I fixed it for you.

Comment: What MIB file is defining .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.255.2.2.11471 ? I can't find it online. If you look there, it will define what type the variable is intended to be.

Comment: @Jolta Hi!, this OID is custom, point to a script in python, by the snmp config using pass_persist, the output of this python script is te first output of my question

Comment: Well, if the python script is providing a different data type than you expected, you should be troubleshooting the script. Could you post a minimum example that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The last few bytes indeed show `Counter32` as its type byte is `0x41`. So there is nothing wrong with NET-SNMP, and you will have to check the agent documentation to dig further.